# Aysnc/Await Vs. Task/Continuation UI Control Access

Tags: c#, task, .net-4.5, async-await

All, I have a situation where I have been asked to multi-thread a large 'Cost-Crunching' algorithm. I am relatively experienced with `Task`s and would be confident in adopting a pattern like

```
CancellationTokenSource cancelSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
CancellationToken token = cancelSource.Token;
TaskScheduler uiScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();

Task<bool> asyncTask = null;
asyncTask = Task.Factory.StartNew<bool>(() =>
    SomeMethodAsync(uiScheduler, token, _dynamic), token);

asyncTask.ContinueWith(task =>
{
    // For call back, exception handling etc.
}, uiScheduler);
```

and then for any operation where I need to provide and UI operation, I would use

```
Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    mainForm.progressLeftLabelText = _strProgressLabel;
}, CancellationToken.None, 
   TaskCreationOptions.None, 
   uiScheduler);
```

Where this might be wrapped up in a method.

Now, I realise that I can make all this much less complicated, and leverage the `async/await` keywords of .NET 4.5. However, I have some questions: if I have a long running method that I launch using

```
// Start processing asynchroniously.
IProgress<CostEngine.ProgressInfo> progressIndicator =
    new Progress<CostEngine.ProgressInfo>();
cancelSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
CancellationToken token = cancelSource.Token;
CostEngine.ScriptProcessor script = new CostEngine.ScriptProcessor(this);
await script.ProcessScriptAsync(doc, progressIndicator, token);
```

where `CostEngine.ProgressInfo` is some basic class used to return progress information and the method `ProcessScriptAsync` is defined as

```
public async Task ProcessScriptAsync(SSGForm doc, IProgress<ProgressInfo> progressInfo,
                                     CancellationToken token, bool bShowCompleted = true)
{
    ...
    if (!await Task<bool>.Run(() => TheLongRunningProcess(doc)))
        return
    ...
}
```

---

I have two questions:

1. To get `ProcessScriptAsync` to return control to the UI *almost* immediately I await on a new `Task<bool>` delegate (this seemingly avoids an endless chain of `async`/`await`s). **Is this the right way to call `ProcessScriptAsync`?** ['Lazy Initialisation', by wrapping in an outer method?]
2. To access the UI from within `TheLongRunningProcess`, do I merely pass in the UI `TaskScheduler` `uiScheduler`; i.e. `TheLongRunningProcess(doc, uiScheduler)`, then use:

---

```
Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    mainForm.progressLeftLabelText = _strProgressLabel;
}, CancellationToken.None, 
   TaskCreationOptions.None, 
   uiScheduler);
```

as before?

Sorry about the length and thanks for your time.

Comment: Since you have two questions they really should be asked in two different questions, not one.

Comment: But that would mean replicating most of the question. I always think/worry about this, but it seems overkill to replicate what is above the line when the questions are so heavily related...

Comment: Meh.  Most of this doesn't really apply to the second question and doesn't need to be there.  It also allows you to get an answer to one question but not the other, should someone know the answer to only one.  If you ask both, you limit responses to people who know the answer to both.

Comment: You think I should edit and go for another question then? What I will say though, is that, it is highly unlikely someone will know the answer to 1. and not 2.

Comment: True, but it's also highly likely someone would know the answer to 2 and not one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It depends.  You've shown a lot of code, and yet omitted the one bit that you're actually asking a question about.  First, without knowing what the code is we can't know if it's actually going to take a while or not.  Next, if you await on a task that's already completed it will realize this, and not schedule a continuation but instead continue on (this is an optimization since scheduling tasks is time consuming).  If the task you await isn't completed then the continuation will still be executed in the calling `SynchronizationContext`, which will again keep the UI thread busy.  You can use `ConfigureAwait(false)` to ensure that the continuation runs in the thread pool though.  This should handle both issues.  Note that by doing this you can no longer access the UI controls in the `...` sections of `ProcessScriptAsync` (without doing anything special).  Also note that since `ProcessScriptAsync` is now executing in a thread pool thread, you don't need to use `Task.Run` to move the method call to a background thread.
2. That's one option, yes.  Although, if you're updating the UI based on progress, that's what `IProgress` is for.  I see you're using it already, so that is the preferable model for doing this.  If this is updating a separate type of progress than the existing `IProgress` you are passing (i.e. the status *text*, rather than the percent complete as an int) then you can pass a second.

Comment: Thanks very much for your time. The code I have ommitted 9the `...`s and the code in `TheLongRunningProcess(doc)` is VAST. `TheLongRunningProcess(doc)` will itself call a multitude of other methods and I want to multithread, with the minimum amount of fuss/work. For 2., the UI access is moving the cellected cell around an Excel workbook (controlled by SpreadsheetGear). So it is nothing to do with the progress, but give an indication of what part of the script is currently being executed.

Comment: @Killercam `"So it is nothing to do with the progress, but give an indication of what part of the script is currently being executed."` The part of the script being executed *is* an indication of the progress, that's the whole point of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think trying to switch back and forth between a background thread (for CPU intensive operations or IO operations with no `async` support) and the UI thread (to manipulate UI controls) is often a sign of bad design. Your calculations and your UI code should be separate.

If you're doing this just to notify the UI of some sort of progress, then use `IProgress<T>`. Any marshaling between threads then becomes the responsibility of the implementation of that interface and you can use [`Progress<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193692.aspx), which does it correctly using the `SynchronizationContext`.

If you can't avoid mixing background thread code and UI thread code and your UI work isn't progress reporting (so `IProgress<T>` won't fit), I would probably enclose each bit of background thread code into its own `await Task.Run()`, and leave the UI code top level.

Your solution of using a single `Task.Run()` to run the background thread code and then switch to the UI thread using `StartNew()` with `uiScheduler` will work too. In that case, some helper methods might be useful, especially if you wanted to use `await` in the UI code too. (Otherwise, you would have to remember to double `await` the result of `StartNew()`)

Yet another option would be create a `SwitchTo(TaskScheduler)` method, which would return a custom awaiter that continues on the given scheduler. Such method was in some of the async CTPs, but it was removed because it was [deemed too dangerous when it comes to handling exceptions](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/async/thread/078c7e77-5b16-4130-bbf5-c8e6ac82effa#4f40e5ef-bf29-4b1a-a4df-30f8df7bf3fc).

Comment: just a quick one; I understand that I _should_ use IProgress object to update the UI and that doing otherwise is bad design. However, one thing that is done in the script processor is going through worksheets getting commands, so inevitably I need access to the UI controls - so I will need to change the TaskScheduler contex at some point.